# ASP.NET Dynamic Menu

Tags: asp.net, menu

I have to create a Dynamic menu in ASP.NET. I want to use dynamic LinkButtons (or can be a Menu Control), but should be appended with sequence numbers. Eg: 1,2,3a 3b etc..and these sequcenes could be dynamic. Any idea. I used a repeater with a label and LinkButton in it, but having problems with view state. Any idea how to append sequence to menu??

Comment: I'm confused slightly, is this anything more then a foreach statement on a property within your model which exposes your _LinkButton_ list?

Comment: I could do that, but I want the sequence as a seperate control, not appended to the link button test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you have two paradigms with web applications, at least from this conversation's standpoint.

1. Stream out the HTML, creating it as you stream
2. Create containers that can bind to data and shape the data

Your concept seems to be "only #1 is dynamic", but that is not true. Any time you can change the data and get a different output, you are dealing with something dynamic. My personal feeling is shape the menu data prior to binding. This cannot always be done, but more oft than not, it can. The second method would be to attach to an event like a item binding or row binding event. Controlling the HTML stream and writing out individual items is generally my last resort.

Now to the viewstate issue. Viewstate is a bastard when you start adding things to an item after binding and semi-problematic when you are playing the dynamic game from #1 above. The problem is things added after the initial definition cannot easily be set up with automagic bits. You end up having to rebind each time. This is why shaping data and then binding is superior. Even in cases where you have to rebuild, you can cache the shaped data and quickly rebind. It takes more "up front" work, but is less problematic.

The actual container you are binding with is inconsequential. Unless you can't use the menu control for some reason (other than having to dynamically add, which can be solved by playing with the bound data), I would head this direction. Actually, I would head this direction and use the CSS friendly adapters so you can alter the look and feel more easily. :-)